# Write a pyspark dataframe to text without changing its structure

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe as shown below

```
+--------------------+
|               speed|
+--------------------+
|[5.59239, 2.51329...|
|[0.0191166, 0.169...|
|[0.561913, 0.4098...|
|[0.393343, 0.3580...|
|[0.118315, 0.1183...|
|[0.831407, 0.4470...|
|[1.49012e-08, 0.1...|
|[0.0411047, 0.152...|
|[0.620069, 0.8262...|
|[0.20373, 0.20373...|
+--------------------+
```

How can I write this dataframe to CSV such that I save it as it is shown above.Currently I tried coalesce but it saved as below

```
"[5.59239, 2.51329, 0.141536, 1.27485, 2.35138, 12.9668, 12.9668, 2.52421, 0.330804, 0.459188, 0.459188, 0.651573, 3.15373, 6.11923, 8.8445, 8.0871, 0.855173, 1.43534, 1.43534, 1.05988, 1.05988, 0.778344, 1.20522, 1.70414, 1.70414, 0.0795492, 1.10385, 1.4759, 1.64844, 0.82941, 1.11321, 1.37977, 0.849902, 1.24436, 1.24436, 0.698651, 0.791467, 0.636781, 0.666729, 0.666729, 0.45688, 0.45688, 0.158829, 2.12693, 29.8682, 29.8682, 9.62536, 3.40384, 2.51002, 1.55077, 1.01774, 0.922753, 0.922753, 0.0438924, 0.530669, 0.879573, 0.627267, 0.0532846, 0.0890066, 0.0884833, 0.140008, 0.147534, 0.0180038, 0.0132851, 0.112785, 0.112785, 0.22997, 0.22997, 0.0524423, 0.141886, 0.328422,............]"
```

But I want to save it in the format such that it is a proper excel file,with speed as column name and its values as a list of lists.

**I dont want to use topandas() as it is memory intensive**

If i have over emphasised/under emphasised sth,please let me know in the comments.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I resolved this!

```
df_Welding_amp.rdd.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile('home/ram/file.csv')
```

Though I didnt get exactly as a list of lists, I was able to successfully get in row format as below

```
Row(speed='[5.59239, 2.51329, 0.141536, 1.27485, 2.35138, 12.9668, 12.9668, 2.52421, 0.330804, 0.459188, 0.459188, 0.651573, 3.15373, 6.11923, 8.8445, 8.0871, 0.855173, 1.43534, 1.43534, 1.05988, 1.05988, 0.778344, 1.20522, 1.70414, 1.70414, 0.0795492, 1.10385, 1.4759, 1.64844, 0.82941........
.....]

Row(speed='[0.0191166, 0.169978, 0.226254, 0.149923, 0.149923, 0.505102, 0.505102, 0.369975, 0.305384, 0.154693, 0.224818, 0.875909, 0.875909, 2.5506, 6.06761, 5.0829, 4.46667, 2.16333, 3.74257, 3.74257, 2.33873, 1.39336, 1.56772, 0.889895, 0.249284, 0.249284, 0.132409, 0.177825, 0.270215, 0.398466, 2.3726, 4.87186, 4.05198, 2.23753, 0.266356, 0.513157, 0.78962, 0.523164, 0.138469, 0.315834, 0.315834]
```

Answer (score -1):

df.coalesce(1).write.option("header","true").csv("file:///s/tesing")

Comment: This gives me a list as I tried above,I want a list of lists as I have it in pyspark dataframe.

Comment: Yes exactly, each row in the pyspark as a list!

Comment: are you getting everything in single line?

Comment: Yes, as of now I get it like that

Comment: it wont support that list in csv file better to remove the list parenthesis then you will get in rows.

Comment: I didn't get you!, you mean remove that list symbol ' [ ' from dataframe?